# firewalld, removing custom created service / linux

Tags: bash, firewalld

I'm adding the new custom service by command

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-service=ssh2
```

but can't find how to remove it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old question; however, I think this would be useful to share.

When you create a service, a `<service-name>.xml` file will be created at `/etc/firewalld/services/`

Now, when you delete a custom service, make sure you delete the corresponding file(s) - as there may be a `.xml.old` file for that service - too.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service=ssh2
rm -f /etc/firewalld/services/ssh2.xml*
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Check to see if your service is still available or not:

```
firewall-cmd --info-service=ssh2
```

This should return an error. :)

Comment: --permanent is correct

Answer (score 3):

I suggest:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-service=ssh2
```

See: http://www.firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd.html

Comment: Nop , it is not working, after removing that way , then cmd --zone=public --permanent --remove-service=ssh2  and reloading firewalld, and adding the service with the same name, getting : Error: NAME_CONFLICT: new_service(): 'ssh2'